# Why am I receiving an error message when attempting NSScanner to use in a NSString statement?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, sigabrt, nsscanner

I would like to know why I get an error message

```
Thread 1: Program received signal: "SIGABRT")
```

When I use this line of code:

```
NSScanner *userEntered = [[NSScanner alloc] scannerWithString:temp];
```

The error is:

```
2011-04-18 02:06:11.995 XXX[25929:207] -[NSConcreteScanner scannerWithString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6816bc0
2011-04-18 02:06:11.999 XXX[25929:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteScanner scannerWithString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6816bc0'
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

+scannerWithString is a class method and should be used the following way:

```
NSScanner *userEntered = [NSScanner  scannerWithString:temp];
```